# Elasticsearch How to query data without aaa attribute instead of data with null aaa attribute

Tags: elasticsearch

> Elasticsearch How to query data without aaa attribute instead of data with null aaa attribute

**e.g.**:
I have 3 data in my_index

```json
{
    "commission_number": "0001",
    "block_status": null
}

{
    "commission_number": "0002",
    "block_status": "123"
}

{
    "commission_number": "0003"
}
```

**I just wanna find the data with commission_number 0003, not 0001.**

The following query will find the data with commission_number 0001 together.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "!_exists_:block_status"
    }
  },
  "size": 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I introduce a `runtime` field. `doc` and `params['_source']` are the `java.util.Map` interface. `doc` contains all fields of mapping. `params['_source']` contains all fields of document. Let's check the availability for key with a field name in the `runtime` field

Documents

```
PUT /missing_field/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"commission_number":"0001","block_status":null}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"commission_number":"0002","block_status":"123"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"commission_number":"0003"}
```

Search query with the runtime field

```
GET /missing_field/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "is_field_missed": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "script": {
                "source": """
                    String fieldName = params.missing_field;
                    emit(!params['_source'].containsKey(fieldName));
                """,
                "params": {
                    "missing_field": "block_status"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "is_field_missed": true
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "commission_number",
        "is_field_missed"
    ],
    "_source": false
}
```

Response

```
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "missing_field",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "3",
                "_score" : 1.0,
                "fields" : {
                    "commission_number" : [
                        "0003"
                    ],
                    "is_field_missed" : [
                        true
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If you want to check a missing value of filed, then use `doc['field_name'].size() == 0`